# How to save coordinates/AXIS (x;y) for the array of 100 elements?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, optimization

1. There is a JSON method. (We send POST -> get 100+ elements)
2. We need to save this 100+ elements by X and Y face coordinates of the picture.
3. In different cases - we need to work with each coordinate (e.a. only 3-4 points of eyebrow). It should be stored in Integer (calculate it...).

   ```
   struct JsonFaceApi {
       let mouth_upper_lip_left_contour2: Integer
       let mouth_upper_lip_top: Integer
       let mouth_upper_lip_left_contour1: Integer
       let left_eye_upper_left_quarter: Integer
       let left_eyebrow_lower_middle: Integer
       let mouth_upper_lip_left_contour3: Integer
       let left_eyebrow_lower_left_quarter: Integer
       let right_eyebrow_lower_left_quarter: Integer
       let right_eye_pupil: Integer
       let mouth_lower_lip_right_contour1: Integer
       let mouth_lower_lip_left_contour2: Integer
       let mouth_lower_lip_right_contour3: Integer
       let mouth_lower_lip_right_contour2: Integer
       let contour_chin: Integer
       let contour_left9: Integer...
   ```

The question is : 
How to optimise stored DATA? e.a. : create `let mouth_upper_lip_left_contour2_x: Integer` and `let mouth_upper_lip_left_contour2_y: Integer`?
Or of course we can create also like `let mouth_upper_lip_left_contour2[]: array` for each element or X array and Y array ? Every opinion is appreciated! )

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? It's not clear at all what you mean by "optimise". This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you intending to optimize for speed, space efficiency, code cleanliness, etc? From a data type perspective, working with points is most often done with `CGPoint`. You could also use `GLKVector2`, or `simd_int2`, or like you suggested, arrays.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Do you need to deal with these points by name (mouth contour, eyebrow, etc). Are you asking for what data structure to use internally, or for how to encode your points into JSON? Will you be rendering these points onto the screen?

Comment: OF COURSE OPTIMISING USAGE OF MEMORY!
IS IT NOT CLEAR ENOUGH???

Comment: If we'll create 100 variables for  X coords.+ 100 vars for Y , it will use 200 variables with INTEGER storage space. + Calculations to store data/calculate data during addressing. If you're a beginner - don't ask, don't waste our time please.

Comment: I asked IN GENERAL , because there different factors, if i knew what is better - i won't ask. Doesn't STACKOVERFLOW created for such kind of questions? Of course if it would be a simple "BOOK question" i won't write it.

Comment: Disrespect from Andrii, Allen.
Duncan C, you're right, it is already named by parts of the FACE, but :

IF we will create 100 for Y and 100 for X - we can use only 20-30, but if we will create an ARRAY of Xs and Ys - we would use only necessary data, it would use less space to store binary data, as if i know it right.

Comment: Downvoted for unacceptable rudeness.

Comment: Whoa, that escalated quickly. @OleksandrZheliezniak, you don't have to be so rude. I don't see how anyone of the commenters disrespected you. Regarding your question, why do you even need to do optimize? Have you run into problems with performance/memory usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiStS.png)

Int16: 2 bytes
Int32 and int: 4 bytes
Int64 : 8 bytes
So Int = Int 32 by default , and for example if you're using 100 x 2 (for X and Y axis) x 32 (bytes) = 6400 bytes.

However if you're using array of Int's , you waste a lot of memory for adressing (system pointers, counter, and so on...).

But from the view of speed and coding time - array is more useful as for me. At least we won't read line-by-line default processor's commands based of variable's memory/code (when it is been decoded into assembler/machine code).
So it should be more convinient to use array at least.

P.S: full space of haters/ non-specified users of PC at all